# I am unable to disappear image after i closed div

Tags: javascript, html

Every thing working Fine but div.closed { display:none;} is not working. when i close div but the book image still appears floating right. I am trying to fix it but still it appears an right side when i close div. I am  trying to make it disappear when i click on Murach's HTML5 and CSS3 or any other heading of list Here is code. I want yu to figure out the problem where i am making mistake otherwise you may also post updated. Waiting for your guidance
code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>FAQs</title>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var faqs = document.getElementById("faqs");
var h2Elements = faqs.getElementsByTagName("h2"); 
var h2Node;
for (var i = 0; i < h2Elements.length; i++) {
h2Node = h2Elements[i];
// Attach event handler
h2Node.onclick = function () {
var h2 = this; // h2 is the current h2Node object
if (h2.getAttribute("class") == "plus")
h2.setAttribute("class", "minus");
else
h2.setAttribute("class", "plus");
if (h2.nextElementSibling.getAttribute("class") == "closed")
h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "open");
else
h2.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "closed");
}
}
}
</script>
<script>
function changeIt (file) {
document.querySelector('.book-image img').setAttribute("src", file);
}
</script> 
<style>
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; width: 1280px; margin: 0 
auto; border: 3px solid blue; margin-top: 30px; }
section { padding: 15px 25px; border: 2px solid green;}
h1 {font-size: 150%;}
h2 { font-size: 120%; padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px; cursor: pointer; }
h2.plus { background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center; }
h2.minus { background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center; }
ul { padding-left: 45px; }
li { padding-bottom: .25em; }
 p { padding-bottom: .25em; padding-left: 25px; }
div.closed { img-display: none;}
div.open { display: block;}
.book-image img { float: right; width: 20%; }
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<section id="faqs">
<div class="book-image"><img src="#"></div>
<h1 style="color:Blue;">Murach products</h1>
<h2 class="plus">Books for web developers</h2>
<div class="closed">
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="changeIt('images/pic1_1.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Murach's HTML5 and CSS3</p></a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="changeIt('images/pic1_2.jpg'); 
return false;"><p>Murach's javascripting and DOM scripting</p></a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="changeIt('images/pic1_3.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Murach's PHP and MYSQL</p></a>
<a href="#" id="4" onclick="changeIt('images/pic1_4.jpg');return false;">
<p>Murach's MYSQL</p></a> 
</div>
<h2 class="plus">Books for Java developers</h2>
<div class="closed">
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="changeIt('images/pic2_1.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Murach's Java Programming</p></a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="changeIt('images/pic2_2.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Murach's Java Servlets and JSP</p></a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="changeIt('images/pic2_3.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Murach's Oracle SQL and PL/SQL</p></a> 
</div>
<h2 class="plus">Books for .Net developers</h2>
<div class="closed">
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="changeIt('images/pic3_1.jpg'); return false;">
<p>C# 2010</p></a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="changeIt('images/pic3_2.jpg'); return false;">
<p>ASP.NET for Web Programming with C# 2010</p></a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="changeIt('images/pic3_3.jpg'); return false;">
<p>Visual Basic 2010</p></a>
<a href="#" id="4" onclick="changeIt('images/pic3_4.jpg'); return false;">
<p>ASP.NET for Web Programming with VB 2010</p></a> 
<a href="#" id="4" onclick="changeIt('images/pic3_5.jpg'); return false;">
<p>SQL Server 2012</p></a>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
div.closed { img-display: none;}
```

(img-display doesnt exist)

change it to

```
div.closed { display: none; }
```

if that doesnt work,

```
div.closed { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Still not working. I am gona share you link with jsfidder